# Looking for alternative LINQ expression(s)

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on a code generator that validated objects based on certain business rules. As an example, I’m curious to find out various ways below logic can be written as LINQ expression.

Assertion should evaluate to true when collection is null OR when count of "TrueAndCorrect" items is anything but 1. One possible solution is:

```
bool assertion = report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection == null 
|| report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection.Count(f => f.FTER99.Equals("TrueAndCorrect")) != 1
```

Are there other ways this LINQ can be expressed as, perhaps more compact, using Any, inverting the operators, or any other?

Comment: This is only one line, I don't get what it's not pretty or good looking to you. what part is less readable.

Comment: It’s not about being pretty or readability in this instance. I have my reasons behind the question.

Comment: Isn’t StackOverflow the right forum for alternate solution to a problem? I’m curious about alternatives to this problem. See blow response from Rene’ for instance. Please provide valuable input instead of questioning people’s intent

Comment: There is a method `Exactly` in https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/. So you can combine it with `Where` and method like `EmptyIfNull` to get what you want

Comment: *Isn’t StackOverflow the right forum ...* Well, for starters, it's not a forum. But pedantry aside, SO is not a good fit for opinion-based questions, which this is.

Comment: We are working on a code generator that validated objects based on certain rules. I was curious to find out various way the logic could be expressed in LINQ. Can a moderator please delete my question. Disappointed by these negative remarks.

Comment: Were only explaining how the site works. Read the site's guidelines on how to ask to prevent getting this kind of feedback. As for your last comment: moderators don't have time read all comments. They respond to flags. But I wouldn't use a flag here because questions having accepted/upvoted answers won't be deleted unless there's a very good reason for it (like containing spam or inappropriate language). See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) if you want to know all ins and outs of Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: You could ask people kindly to change the question or explain in a manner that does not come across as condescending and demoralizing. That would make the site more welcoming, if that’s what you are concerned about. I still don’t understand what I did wrong. My question was valid and the response from the guys in its place making me learning a couple of thing. I’m pretty sure it will benefit others too. We should take  a step back and think before responding with deflating comment just because the question is written in a way that’s not in our tasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the null-propagation operator:

```
bool assertion = report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection?.Count(f => f.FTER99.Equals("TrueAndCorrect")) != 1;
```

Since `null` is not `1` this is also `true` if the collection is `null`.

It would be nice if you don't need to count the whole collection, you already know it's wrong when there's more than one matching element. But I don't know of a built-in method for that. You could write your own extension:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrHasNotExactlyOneMatching<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (source == null) return true;

        bool found = false;
        foreach(T element in source)
        {
            if (!predicate(element)) continue;
            if (found) return true; // this is the second match!
            found = true;
        }
        return !found; // one match found (or not)                                      
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
bool assertion = report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection.IsNullOrHasNotExactlyOneMatching(f => f.FTER99.Equals("TrueAndCorrect"));
```

---

As mentioned by [Rawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305921/alternative-linq-expression/51306174?noredirect=1#comment89589185_51306174) you could shorten the extension using `Take()`:

```
public static bool IsNullOrHasNotExactlyOneMatching<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source?.Where(predicate).Take(2).Count() != 1;
}
```

or do this directly:

```
bool assertion = report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection?.Where(f => f.FTER99.Equals("TrueAndCorrect"))
                       .Take(2).Count() != 1;
```

Both versions only iterate until a second match was found (or until the end if no match was found).

Comment: `.Take(2).Count()` maybe, if you move the condition around.

Comment: Nice . Will wait marking as answer, curious to see what else comes in. Cheers

Comment: @ErshadNozari I actually made a mistake (it was true if it's exaclty 1, not if it's different than 1. Updated my answer.

Comment: Loving the Take(2) suggestion 

Answer (score 2):

The original code is:

```
bool assertion = 
  report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection == null || 
  report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection.Count(
      f => f.FTER99.Equals("TrueAndCorrect")) != 1;
```

There are some problems here.

First, the intention of the null check seems to be "a null collection has the same semantics as an empty collection".  **This is a worst-practice in C#.**  Never do this!  If you want to represent an empty collection, **make an empty collection**.  There's even an `Enumerable.Empty` helper method for you.

So, start with that; the code should be:

```
if (report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection == null) 
  throw some appropriate exception
```

or

```
Debug.Assert(report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection != null);
```

if the condition is impossible.

That leaves us with

```
bool assertion = 
  report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection.Count(
      f => f.FTER99.Equals("TrueAndCorrect")) != 1;
```

This is bad.  Suppose I show you a jar that contains some number of pennies and I ask you "is there exactly one penny in the jar?"  How many pennies do you have to count before you know the answer?  Your code here is counting *all* of them, but you could stop after two.

`Enumerable` gives you a method which *throws* if a sequence is not a singleton, but no method that *tests* it.  Fortunately it is easy to write.  **The best practice here is to write a helper method that has the exact semantics you want**:

```
static class Extensions 
{
  public static bool IsSingleton<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
  {
    bool seenOne = false;
    foreach(T item in items) 
    {
      if (seenOne) return false;
      seenOne = true;
    }
    return seenOne;
  }

  public static bool IsSingleton<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate) =>
      items.Where(predicate).IsSingleton();
}
```

Done.  And now your code is:

```
  if (report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection == null) 
    throw some appropriate exception
  bool assertion = 
    report.DeclarationOfTrusteeCollection.IsSingleton(f => ...);
```

**Write the code so that it reads like what it is logically doing.** That's the beauty and power of LINQ sequence operators.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive response. In this instance assertion needs to be true if collection is null and it’s a valid scenario. Throwing an exception would not be the desired outcome for us. We need to respond with and appropriate validation error in case of null. The collection is sent to us and we don’t have control over the way it’s been implemented. We are merely responsible for writing business rules against it.

Comment: @ErshadNozari: Well, you know your customer better than I do, but a word of advice:  **if you start throwing every time they pass null, they will stop passing null**. :-)

Comment: @ErshadNozari: If you *must* be in a position where null collections are treated as empty, then the best practice in C# is **at the entrypoint where the bad collection comes in** do a `foos = foos ?? Enumerable.Empty<Foo>();` so that *immediately* you go from having an invalid null collection to a valid empty collection.  You then never have to worry about dereferencing null in the rest of your code.